# Tweak the controller in returning the JSON Object to a specific format

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Anyone knows how can i return the JSON Object in a certain format through the use of a controller such that it would display the data in a specified order as shown below. I have tried to researched for solution online and found that most of them uses controller however i am confused about the solution that they have provided.

Current Result

```
{
    "Table:" [
        {
            "ED_Name": "Ang Mo Kio GRC",
            "GARO_Name": "Central CDC"
        },
        {
            "ED_Name": "Bishan-Toa Payoh GRC",
            "GARO_Name": "Central CDC"
        },
    ]
}
```

Expected Result

```
{
    "Table": [
        {
            "Central CDC": ["Ang Mo Kio GRC"]
        },
        {
            "North-East CDC": ["Pasir Ris - Punggol GRC", "Tampines GRC"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Code for the Controller

```
public class GAROController : ApiController
{

    Database_Access_Data.db dblayer = new Database_Access_Data.db();

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/GARO/GetGAROList")]
    public DataSet CheckLockedOut()
    {
        DataSet ds = dblayer.GetGAROList();
        return ds;
    }
}
```

And code which calls the stored procedure from the database:

```
public DataSet GetGAROList()
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GetCDC", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
```

Stored Procedure to retrieve the data from the database

```
  /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetCDC]    Script Date: 4/12/2018 
  5:30:01 PM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCDC]
  AS 
  BEGIN 
  Select E.Name AS ED_Name, G.Name AS GARO_Name
  From ElectoralDivision E
  INNER JOIN GARO G ON G.ID = E.GAROID
  ORDER BY G.Name, E.Name
  END
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Is it the code that causes your confusion? If so, what causes this confusion?

Comment: The problem with this code is that it return the data directly from the stored procedure in the database as shown above under Current. i would like to modify the data such that it would be in this format instead of the original format before returning back to the view as shown in Intended

Comment: Your 'Current Result' is inconsistent and can't be right: it starts with **`[`** and ends with **`}`**.

Comment: Also, your 'Expected Result' shows data that seems to be pulled from the air. None of the values in `["Sengkang West GRC", "def"]` can be found in your example. Without further detail, this can't be answered properly.

Comment: For the Current Result, i have make a mistake while typing the result and have edited it

Comment: For the Expected result, I have make some amends to the example  however my main concern will be is it possible to convert the Json object into something like the expected result

Comment: Maybe also `"Bishan-Toa Payoh GRC"` needs to be present in the first output array? Then it would make sense. Or if not, please explain why not.

Comment: hmm ok sure but may i know how can i achieve the example that i have stated in the example(Expected). Do i need to convert the JSON object into an JSON Array or Create an JSON Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom json converter that convert each and every property to your custom format.

```
public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray jArray = new JArray();
        if (value != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)value)
            {
                JObject jObject = new JObject();
                jObject.Add(new JProperty(item.Key, JArray.FromObject(item.Value)));
                jArray.Add(jObject);
            }
        }

        JObject jMainObject = new JObject();
        jMainObject.Add(new JProperty("Table", jArray));
        jMainObject.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

And you can use above converter like

```
//Your DataSet filled with stored procedure result.
DataSet ds = dblayer.GetGAROList();

//Populate DataTable from above DataSet
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

//Project your data from DataTable to Dictionary
var result = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by row.Field<string>("GARO_Name") into grp
              select new
              {
                  GARO_Name = grp.Key,
                  ED_Name = grp.Select(x => x.Field<string>("ED_Name")).ToList()
              }).ToDictionary(x => x.GARO_Name, x => x.ED_Name);

//Use above Converter 
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, new CustomJsonConverter());

//Print formatted json to console
Console.WriteLine(JObject.Parse(json));
```

**Output:**

[image]